# Regular Expression - Get String between 2 Strings

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am facing issues extracting a string between two strings/pattern.

This is what I got so far:
https://regex101.com/r/yuoQha/1

[image]

The problem I have is that I receive a way too long string with the RegEx code I have designed, because it seems that RegEx searches from backwards on?

I marked in red what I only need.
How should I modify my RegEx pattern? Does Lookahead/Lookbehind have something to do with the solution?
At the end it should work with VBA. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
OEM[]]]><[\/]Name><Value>(.*?NameValueList.*?)(?=<[\/]Value><[\/]NameValueList)
```

It matches exactly what is orange in your image.

FYI, the `?` after the `.*` are to make it non-greedy. Needed to add `NameValue` in there since you want it to appear once in your pattern.

Comment: worked for me, thanks. still try to understand that logic though. why was there a down vote actually, if there are solutions to questions? did I miss something?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2005/08/19/are-you-greedy-or-lazy/